# Check if substring is present in another string, regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have two strings:

```
var first = "913 DE 6D 3T 222"
var second = "913 DE 3T 222"
```

I want to check if `second` is present in `first`, preferably with **`regex`**. The problem is that `indexOf` or `includes` returns that `second` is **not** present in `first`, which is wrong (only `6D` is the difference):

```
first.indexOf(second)
-1

first.includes(second)
false
```

Comment: What is your definition of "contains" here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript

Comment: maybe you should split your 2nd string and check if the values are contained in string 1? and second **is not** completely present in first, thats why the methods work correctly

Comment: `indexOf` works as expected

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest No it should not.

Comment: @user1665355, got it, and how about regex solution?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest would be great with regex solution. and order of words is not sufficient to take in account, only if all characters or numbers are present from one string in another

Comment: @user1665355, check my regex solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) methods.

```js
var first = "913 DE 6D 3T 222";
var second = "913 DE 3T 222";

console.log(
  second
  // split the string by space
  .split(' ')
  // check all strings are contains in the first
  .every(function(v) {
    return first.indexOf(v) > -1;

    // if  you want exact word match then use regex with word
    // boundary although you need to escape any symbols which
    // have special meaning in regex but in your case I think all are 
    // alphanumeric char so which is not necessary

    // return (new RegExp('\\b' + v + '\\b')).test(first);
  })
)
```

---

**FYI :** For older browser check [polyfill option of `every` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill).

---

Comment: @user1665355 : check with regex option added in the comment

Answer (score 1):

This is a more elegant solution.

First of all, I'm using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. In our case it is returning an array something like this:

`[true,true,true,true]`. Then, using `reduce` function and `logical operators` we will obtain one single value. If array containes at least one `false` value, then final result will be `false`.

```js
var first = "913 DE 6D 3TT 222";
var second = "913 DE 3T 222";
console.log(second.split(' ').map(function(item){
    return first.includes(item);
}).reduce(function(curr,prev){
    return curr && prev;
}));
```

Comment: @Alexandru-Iounut Mihai This will check if all characters and numbers are present in first from second?

Comment: @user1665355, yes, I used a logical Operators

Comment: that returns false if first string is `var first = "913 DE 6D 3TT 222".split(' ');`, note one more `T` in `3TT`. Should be true still, because all characters in second still present in first.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `String.match()` function and a specific regex pattern:

I've change the `first` string to make a more complex case, duplicate `DE` value added.

```js
var first = "913 DE 6D 3T 222 DE",
    second = "913 DE 3T 222",
    count = second.split(' ').length;

var contained = (count == first.match(new RegExp('(' + second.replace(/\s/g, "|") + ')(?!.*\\1)', "gi")).length);
console.log(contained);
```

`(?!.*\1)` - is negative lookahead assertion to avoid duplicate matches